# differential equation of conics in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1) Find differential equation of conics in the plane with given latus-rectum p using polar coordinates $( r,\theta) $ .

Is the classical ODE  $ u'' + u = p $ correct in this context? (variable u = 1/r, prime with respect to $ \theta$).

2) Also find differential equation of conics in the plane with given eccentricity $\epsilon$.

EDIT 1:

For the second part of constant eccentricity I obtained (self-answered/derived) the following differential equation by differentiation of classical conic polar equation.

$$ p/r = ( 1- \epsilon \cos\theta ) $$

In the particular case when arbitrary line is taken as x-axis, not generally valid.

If $ \phi $ is the angle conic tangent makes to an arbitrary line and $\theta$ is angle which radius vector makes to same line, then for same $ \epsilon  $

$$ \dfrac {\cos (\phi-\theta)}{\cos \phi} = \epsilon  $$

EDIT2:

and for same $ p $

$$ cot(\phi-\theta) \cot\theta   + r/p = 1 $$